# How does validate phase does it's action in maven where it does not have a plugin associated with it?

Tags: java, maven

I posted question regarding maven before also. I have a new doubt. when I try to check the plugins for each phase of default maven build lifecycle I saw there is not plugin for `validate` phase or `process sources`. Why it is like that? I knew each phase does a task and to do a task in maven you must need a plugin.

Here is the [link](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging)  for all the plugins for default life cycle.

Comment: Apart from that your link links to a very old version...your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty phases are meant to be used by other plugins that you might or might not add to your POM.

If you e.g. want to generate source code with some maven plugin, you would bind it to the `generate-sources` phase.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to mean here. As per my understanding we can add plugin to any phase like ```packaging``` etc. is it correct? Therefore, my question is why these are empty, it is they want developer to decide what plugin/action he/she wants to perform on that phase? I am bit new here so if you can explain a bit that would be helpful.

Comment: plus i executed ```mvn validate``` , i noticed when it executed no plugin fired. is that mean no action taken place at that time ?

Comment: Yes, it is empty space that can be filled by the developer. The lifecycle describes abstractly, which things should happen in which order. This guides the developer where to put the plugins.

Comment: I may be that `mvn validate` does not run any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that when added to the POM, will bind by default to `validate`, for example [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html).